# How to set a global variable in another module?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-module

I want to pass an instance (like a pointer) from my main module to another module, so I will be able to change the entry value of my main module. In my example - when the user click on a button it's sent the object by reference using the lambda function and everything is ok.

However in my calc.py module I have a lot of functions. So I need to attach the entry object to all my buttons and the receiving functions in the second module.

Is there is simple way to pass the address of the entry object to the second module so all the functions there will be able to access the object (so like it will be globally for them) without having to explicitly pass it to each function?

I attached some part of my code. I'm pretty beginner in Python.

MyApp.py

```
# module 1 (main)


import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk
from calc import* 


window = tkinter.Tk()

e1 = tkinter.ttk.Entry(frame5, width=62)
e1.grid()

insert7_btn = tkinter.ttk.Button(frame5, text="7", command=lambda: insert_num(7,e1))
insert7_btn.grid()

button_plus = tkinter.ttk.Button(frame5, text="+", command=lambda: memory('+',e1))
button_plus.grid()

....
....
window.mainloop()
```

calc.py

```
# module 2

import tkinter          
import tkinter.ttk
import math           

def insert_num(number,e1):
    .....


def memory(operation,e1):
    ..... 
......
```

Comment: Import Myapp in calc and use Myapp.e1. No need to have it as a parameter.

Comment: So what if I'm passing a variable by reference. I asked how to do it in a different way !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217538/discussion-between-eliran-n-and-bryan-oakley).

Comment: @eric: that will result in a circular import - you can't have MyApp.py import calc.py and also have calc.py import MyApp.py.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to put all the functions in `calc.py` inside a class and pass `e1` when creating an instance of the class:

```
# calc.py

class CalcUtils:
    def __init__(self, e1):
        self.e1 = e1

    def insert_num(self, number):
        # use self.e1 here
        ...
    
    def memory(self, operation):
        # use self.e1 here
        ...
```

Then in your main app, create an instance of `CalcUtils` with `e1` as argument and use the instance to call the required function:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from calc import CalcUtils

window = tk.Tk()

e1 = ttk.Entry(window, width=62)
e1.grid()

utils = CalcUtils(e1)

insert7_btn = ttk.Button(window, text='7', command=lambda: utils.insert_num(7))
insert7_btn.grid()

button_plus = ttk.Button(window, text='+', command=lambda: utils.memory('+'))
button_plus.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh..So you're importing the class that you created from calc, creating an object from that class and the same time passing e1 - using the init you store him to utils.e1 automatically. and then through the object you can access the methods within the class by using lambda.
I will have to change everything to: 
utils.method_name in the main module
and self.e1 within the methods in calc

I was looking for shorter way without do many changes, But really nice idea to implement it. Thank you very much for your reply !